# Android Studio setup - Clear Read-Only Status

Tags: git, android-studio

Permission to write to certain folder isn't obtained. Android Studio asks this. Only thing I can click on "Cancel" button.

[image: Clear read only-status]

Afterwards, when I want to leave Android Studio I get "could not save project".

[image: Could not save project]

- Project is downloaded from git repository.
- Works fine on other macs.
- Project is downloaded to user/projects/project-name.
- Tried to play with permissions without success
- Tried to change project directory location (another project in the same directory is working)
- Installed all possible packages

[image: Permissions on files in project folder]

Locked icons in Android studio.

[image]

I need any suggestion in what direction to look for solution?

Comment: change you project directory location and try.

Comment: I did try. It is set on the same location.

Comment: The Android Studio process is owned by what user ?

Comment: What does "owned" mean? When I start it the user is "myname"

Comment: please pastebin.com the output of `ls -R -alh` on your project directory.

Comment: have you tried `sudo chmod -R 777 /<path>/<to>/<your>/<project>` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GF1sDB3k here is ls -R -alh

Answer (score 33):

The most likely explanation is that the directory and all its files are owned by a different user account on the system. Normally the "Clear Read-Only Access" dialog will fix up read permission problems if it's possible to do so; if it's not (because the files are owned by another user), the dialog will refuse to let you click the OK button.

You can confirm this by using the `ls` command from the MacOS terminal. Here's an example from a random project of mine.

```
sbarta-macbookpro2:~/AndroidStudioProjects/ASProject$ ls -alh
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 foo   eng   438B Jan  9 10:54 local.properties
-rw-r--r--  1 foo   eng   853B Jan  9 10:54 gradle.properties
drwxr-xr-x  3 foo   eng   102B Jan  9 10:54 gradle
```

If you run `man ls` you can read the man page for the `ls` command and get a lot more information on the output from the command, but the single "w" character in the output for each file tells me that those files are only writable by the file's owner. Those files are all owned by the foo user (which is what the third column of output means). I'm not foo when I'm running Android Studio, so I can't write to those files, and since I'm not foo, I don't have permissions to give myself write access to them.

You can fix it with the following command. Be very careful you use the correct path when you run this command; making large-scale filesystem changes under `sudo` can do a lot of damage if you make a mistake.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /path/to/project/directory
```

There's probably a way to fix this through the Finder UI, but the command-line is pretty easy.

It will ask you for an administrator password, and after that it should make you the owner of those files and the "Clear Read-Only Status" dialog should work for you.

Comment: That shows the top-level directory. Are there files under it with permissions problems?

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem with Android Studio for Linux (IntelliJ IDEA)
It looked like this: when I was trying to edit some project files (i.e. build.txt or build.gradle) the Studio  displayed a "Clear Read-Only Status" dialog window with the "OK" button throwing another warning "Failed to change read-only status for the following files:"

[image]

Steps to fix ( I will use the user "alex")
1) Ensure you are under the right user

```
echo $USER

alex
```

2) Check the ownership rights of the troubled file (Example:"build.txt)

```
 ls -als Downloads/android-studio/

total 56
 4 drwxrwxr-x  8 alex alex  4096 Nov 10 11:51 .
 4 drwxr-xr-x 16 alex alex  4096 Apr 25 11:13 ..
 4 drwxrwxr-x  3 alex alex  4096 Feb  7 15:44 bin
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 root root    14 Nov  9 10:26 build.txt
 4 drwxrwxr-x  4 alex alex  4096 Nov 10 11:51 gradle
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 alex alex  1934 Nov  9 10:26 Install-Linux-tar.txt
 4 drwxrwxr-x  6 alex alex  4096 Nov 10 11:51 jre
 4 drwxrwxr-x  5 alex alex  4096 Nov 10 11:51 lib
 4 drwxrwxr-x  2 alex alex  4096 Nov 10 11:51 license
12 -rw-r--r--  1 alex alex 11352 Nov  9 10:26 LICENSE.txt
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 alex alex   397 Nov  9 10:26 NOTICE.txt
 4 drwxrwxr-x 39 alex alex  4096 Nov 10 11:51 plugins
```

That build.txt is owned by the root! That's why the Android Studio cannot edit it.

3) Fix the ownership rights for the whole project directory

```
sudo chown -R $USER /project/directory/
```

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation. you saved my ass!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and was playing with permissions and settings for a while. I found 2 solutions for this problem:

1. Just launch your Android Studio from the terminal using `sudo`. For    example
   `cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/
   sudo ./studio`
2. Choose a folder with your android projects -> Get Info -> scroll down to 'Sharing & Permissions' -> set the permission for 'staff' as 'Read & Write' -> press small settings wheel icon below -> choose 'Apply to enclosed items'.

If there is no possibility to choose 'Apply to enclosed items' than u need to unlock the small lock icon first.

Answer (score 3):

- Close Android Studio.
- Delete .idea folder (It's inside your project root directory).
- Start Android Studio and open project.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows I fixed the issue (after I had deleted .idea folder. I don't know if that makes any difference) by Selecting `Import Non-Android Studio Project` option from the `Welcome to Android Studio` screen. You get this screen when no project is open.

Things that I tried but didn't work for me:

1. executed as admin from cmd ----> `attrib -r +s c:\workingdir and attrib -r +s c:\workingdir\*`
2. Changed the read only flag from properties.
3. Changed permissions while in safe mode.

Answer (score 2):

The most easiest way is to open the class file in android studio and then goto file > Make file writable.
please check this:
http://android.okhelp.cz/android-studio-lock-unlock-file-make-read-only-or-writable/

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My whole project is uneditable and the "make writable" is already set to writable....

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving read-write permission to your Android project, its sub-modules, their sub-modules, theirs etc. ...

```
yourName-MacBook-Pro:androidProjectsFolder yourusername$ sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

(Don't forget the dot "." at the end)

-R stands for recursion. 
777 is for "read-write"

EDIT: Remember, checking if permission is causing the problem first is advised. In Mac, go to the path of trouble file path, right click, click "Get info", scroll down, see which permission is given (Read Only, Read&Write, Custom etc.). If the problem is not permission, giving high access level may cause security issues.

Answer (score 1):

CD to your project root path and run this command `sudo chown -R YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME`

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

1, change something of the file;

2, a dialog is shown, in right down corner should be a line asking you "do you want to remove delete";

3, check that line;

4. press ok.

the read only will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chmod 777 -R 'the path of your project'.
```

It is not good for your security but it works for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way to solve this problem is:

- Download VS studio from Microsoft.
- Just save and close your project completely.
- Now edit or Open your file with VS studio.
- Make changes and save it.
- Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but I will still post it for future readers.
If you're dual booting between linux and windows, this problem normally happens when windows goes into hibernate mode or if fast startup is enabled on windows.

Just switch to windows and perform a restart, or in the later go to the power options (in windows) and uncheck fast startup option.

Hope this helps someone :)