# Android Studio, Clear Read-Only Status not working

Tags: android, windows, windows-8, android-studio, file-permissions

When I open Android studio a dialog pops up saying `Clear Read-Only Status`. When I click `Ok` on the dialog nothing happens.

When I try and remove Read Only from the folders it just pops back to Read Only.

I have tried running the `attrib -r` command but that didn't help.
I have tried running Android Studio as Admin but that didn't help.

OS: Windows 8 x64

Comment: Make sure your files are not located in a "protected area" (such as Program Files). The behavior in Windows 8 was changed so that even applications with Admin rights can not access files in some locations without elevation and explicit user consent. Applications need to implement this and most do not.

Comment: @free3dom they are in C\Users\username\foldername, is that protected? It worked in windows 7.

Comment: Files in that location should be accessible as long as **username** refers to the logged-in user. To rule it out as the problem you could temporarily move the files to the root of your drive and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: [Android Studio setup - Clear Read-Only Status](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21607317/6521116)

Comment: [Android Studio: Bringing back “Clear Read-Only Status” dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43187507/6521116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by just creating another project and moving the assets and source into it.

Comment: can you please explain me in detail how to do it? I have tried many methods but nothing seems to work

Comment: 1) Move original project folder somewhere else, 2) Create new project with same name and package, 3) Drag contents of original project folder into new project folder

Answer (score 1):

In Windows I fixed the issue (after I had deleted *.idea* folder.
I don't know if that makes any difference) by Selecting **Import Non-Android Studio Project** option from the **Welcome to Android Studio** screen. You get this screen when no project is open.

Things that I tried but didn't work for me:

1. executed as admin from cmd
   `attrib -r +s c:\workingdir and attrib -r +s c:\workingdir\*`
2. Changed the read only flag from properties.
3. Changed permissions while in safe mode.