# Android Studio: Bringing back "Clear Read-Only Status" dialog

Tags: android, android-studio, file-permissions

If source file is read only, Android Studio was displaying a dialog and asking if I want to clear read-only status of file so that it will be ready for editing. By mistake I once checked the box that says "Do not show this dialog again" and clicked OK. Since then Android Studio simply clears off read-only status of file and allows to edit without asking for confirmation.

Anyone knows how to bring back that conformation dialog?

Comment: [Android Studio setup - Clear Read-Only Status](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21607317/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `ctrl-shift-A` on windows, or `⇧⌘A` on mac and type "Clear Read-only Status". It will show you where you can make the change in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I caused this problem by forgetting I had used the command /.studio.sh as root user.

The next day I ran /.studio.sh as non root and received the same read only issue.

So make sure if you are on linux to keep the user level consistent.